# Hide and show UITabbar

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I have the problem that I want to show a UITabbar when a specific UITableViewController is shown and the UITabbar should disappear if I go back to the original UITableViewController.

Is this possible?

Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

UITabBar is a UIView, so you can add it to any view you like.